# Scala: Avoid var or mutable type

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability

I have a pseudo-code like shown below. The `ItemChurner.churn()` is abstracted component which generates objects until `x` times, where `x` is unknown. :

```
def func: MyList = {

    var list: MyList = MyList()

    while(ItemChurner.canChurn) {
        list = new MyList(ItemChurner.churn(), list)
    }

    list
}
```

Is there a way to avoid use of `var`?

Comment: you can implement `Iterator` interface like `val iterator = new Iterator {def hasNext = ItemChurner.canChurn; def next = ItemChurner.churn()` , and then `iterator.toList`

Comment: Why are you wrapping the inside of the `while` loop with a try-catch? Shouldn't `ItemChurner` return `false` if there aren't anymore elements?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: right. Corrected the snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `canChurn` works as it should:

```
def func(churner: ItemChurner) = {
  val iterator = new Iterator {
    def hasNext = churner.canChurn
    def next = churner.churn()
  }
  iterator.toList
}
```

---

*About version (of the question) that contained catched exception check for `churn()`:*

If really expect some exceptions, what's the point of `canChurn` then?

Anyway, if you care about exceptions:

```
 Iterator.continually(Try(churner.churn)).takeWhile(_.isSuccess).map(_.get).toList
```

This actually is not much precise, as `churn` might throw some other exception that has to be propagated, so here the scala's [Exception helpers](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.control.Exception$)) come in hand:

```
def step = catching(classOf[NoMoreElementsException]) opt churner.churn()
Iterator.continually(step).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).map(_.get).toList
```

Comment: @dk12, yes. Just realized that if I have canChurn, there is no need to catch exceptions. Thanks for pointing out. Question updated.

Comment: @dk12 I think `Iterator.continually(if (churner.canChurn) Some(churner.churn()) else None).takeWhile(_.isEmpty).map(_.get).toList` is a better choice as it relies only on the exposed part of `churner` capabilities.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh it depends. Catching an exception inside `Try` might be slower, besides code that actually checks for exact exception that signalizes about no more elements is less elegant (might require [Exception helpers](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.control.Exception$))

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do using Simple recursion and avoid `var`. This is the general strategy used in functional programming.

*Use `Vector` instead of `List` for effective `append`*

```
def func[T](): List[T] = {

  @tailrec
  def helper(result: List[T]): List[T] = {
    if (ItemChurner.canChurn) helper(result ++ List(ItemChurner.churn))
    else result
  }

  helper(List.Empty[T])
}
```

*Assuming `ItemChurner.canChurn` does not throw any exception. if it throws exceptions simply wrap it inside `Try`*

Comment: about effectiveness, `List` seems to not be a best choice here as `List ++ List` has linear complexity. `Vector` [has](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) effectively constant append

Comment: @dk14  you are absolutely correct. thanks. edited the ans .

Answer (score 0):

Improving upon [pamu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3798102/pamu)'s answer, you can do something on the lines of;

```
def func: MyList = {
  def process(cur: MyList): MyList = {
    if (ItemChurner.canChurn) process(new MyList(ItemChurner.churn(), cur))
    else cur
  }
  process(new MyList())
}
```